# CSRF-token error in django+nginx+gunicorn in docker

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

I have a problem with CSRF-token error in django+nginx+gunicorn in docker:

Origin checking failed - http://185.255.132.54:5000 does not match any trusted origins.
Such problem on live production server and this problem with dev local server:
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

This error appears only with NGINX port (any POST form, login page too (example.com/admin) (5000 for production and 8001 on dev server), but it's ok on gunicorn port (no static).

I read some that I have to add CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://185.255.132.54:5000', 'http://185.255.132.54', 'https://185.255.132.54:5000'] to production server, but it didn't help.

Here's my code: https://github.com/endlessnights/DjangoDockerNginxSample
(all files, included Dockerfile, docker-compose, project files etc are there)

What have I to do with such problem?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I am also having the issue. Have been scratching my head about it for 2 days now.

Comment: Not yet(( I'll try to figure out how to fix it later and will wait for comments or solutions.

Comment: So if you are running on http instead of https it wont work. This is because Django sends the 'Secure' tag with the cookie. If you don't want to send it the 'Secure' tag. You can set the settings option "CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE" to false

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same issue and I found the solution [here](https://github.com/sissbruecker/linkding/issues/340). I added `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` to my nginx server configuration.